# Music during Shikamaru's fight with Tayuya

Tags: naruto, music

Does anyone know the song used during Shikamaru's fight with Tayuya, when he first uses the Shadow Strangle Technique on her? I've tried to look through OSTs, but I haven't been able pinpoint the exact one.

https://youtu.be/Q9-UBzSS4zM?t=658

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it was an unreleased track called Dangerous! at abot 37 secs in.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBVeRzjWqq8